# Error while reading the file and sending via sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am reading a file and transferring it to a server in C++. Following is the main part of my code:

**Client:**

```
long Begin;
long End;
char * block;

    //Open the file for reading
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(path, ios::in | ios::binary);

    //Calculate the dize of file
Begin = myfile.tellg();
myfile.seekg(0,ios::end);
End = myfile.tellg();
unsigned long size = End - Begin;

int Div = (int)size / 1024;
int Mod = (int)size % 1024;
int len = strlen(name);

    //Send Length of filename
send(theSocket,(const char*)&len,sizeof(int),0);
recv(theSocket, ack,sizeof(ack),0);

    //Send Filename
send(theSocket,name,strlen(name),0);
recv(theSocket, ack,sizeof(ack),0);

    //Send size of file
send(theSocket, (const char*)&size, sizeof(unsigned long), 0);
recv(theSocket, ack,sizeof(ack),0);

    //send file in parts of 1024 bytes
for (int i=0; i<Div; i++)
{
    block = new char[1025];
    myfile.seekg(i*1024);
    myfile.get(block,1024);
            block[1024] = 0;
    send(theSocket,block,1025,0);
    recv(theSocket, ack,sizeof(ack),0);
}

    //send remaining part of file
if (Mod != 0)
{
    block = new char[Mod];
    myfile.seekg(Div*1024);
    myfile.get(block,Mod);
            block[Mod] = 0;
    send(theSocket,block,Mod+1,0);
    recv(theSocket, ack,sizeof(ack),0);
}

myfile.close();
closesocket(theSocket);
WSACleanup();
```

**Server:**

```
while(true)
{
        theClient = accept(listeningSocket,NULL,NULL);
        int namelen;
        unsigned long filelen;
        char * block;
        char * Filename;
        char ack[10] = "Ack";

            //Receive Length of Filename
        recv(theClient,(char *)&namelen,sizeof(int),0);
        send(theClient,ack,sizeof(ack),0);
        Filename = new char [namelen];

            //Receive Filename
        recv(theClient,Filename,namelen,0);
        send(theClient,ack,sizeof(ack),0);

            //open file for writing         
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open(Filename, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);

            //Receive Length of File
        recv(theClient,(char *)&filelen,sizeof(unsigned long),0);
        send(theClient,ack,sizeof(ack),0);

        int Div = (int)filelen / 1024;
        int Mod = (int)filelen % 1024;
        block = new char[1024];

            //receive the file in parts and write to the stream
        for (int i=0; i<Div; i++)
        {
            recv(theClient,block,1025,0);
            myfile << block;
            send(theClient,ack,sizeof(ack),0);
        }

            //write the remaining part of file
        if (Mod != 0)
        {
            block = new char[Mod+1];
            recv(theClient,block,Mod,0);
            myfile << block;
            send(theClient,ack,sizeof(ack),0);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
```

I have successfully created the sockets and made the connection. So giving that code it useless. I am having following two problems:

1. I miss every `1024th` byte at the server. Is this because I am putting `zero` in the last byte of `block`. But I have reserved the space for that `zero` by allocating `1025` bytes.
2. I am unable to handle the `CR/LF` characters. As I am transferring the file in binary mode, I have to take care of `CR/LF` as well. I need to transfer the files regardless of file type. So if `CR/LF` is observed, the string is terminated and the data is not written in file as server.

Kindly help is resolving. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the server is only allocating 1024 bytes to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the result of every `recv()` call and assuming that it fills the buffer you provide.

There is nothing in the TCP or Berkely Sockets API specification that entitles you to do that. `recv()` can deliver anything between 1 byte and the buffer length you specify, or zero, meaning end of stream, or an error. You cannot ignore this result, ever.